# Pandas: Filtering number as string values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to filter column that contains values like this:

```
6 790 750 024   
2 755 740
```

numbers but strings (keeps space delimiter)

```
df[df['user_id'] == '5 756 405']
```

It doesn't work and returns dataframe headers only.
For other columns (without numbers but strings) filtering works fine.

Comment: Strip the additional ending spaces if there are any. Try `df[df['user_id'].str.strip() == '5 756 405']`

Comment: Difficult to say without more context, but what are these numbers?

Comment: @coldspeed this is User ID, data was imported from csv file to dataframe

Comment: @Dark this didn't help ((

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only get the header because none of the entries in your dataframe has a user_id that match '5 756 405'. Maybe you should get some user_id from your dataframe to see their format (it might be something like ' 5 756 405'). You can do that by doing

```
df.user_id.values[i]
```

and try some values of i to get a general idea.